# Loading HTML into div - unusual issue

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have an unusual issue with a website I have created for a friend.

I have created the index.html with links down the left sidebar to remain constant. When you click a link, an external HTML file is called inside the main div in the centre of the page.

This works wonderfully but with one small issue (which is actually an annoying problem)!

If you click the first link, 'products' for example, you can scroll from the left all the way to the right to the last image nicely. If you then click 'fashion', another HTML file is called but it calls it at the stage you left off from 'products' i.e. all the way to the right, and not at the start.

I basically need to force the HTML to call the page at the beginning each time a link is clicked. Here is my weblink for you to see what I am talking about...

http://www.hannahdakin.co.uk/betasite

P.S. I can't find anyone else with a similar issue after looking on forums, but there might be a term for this problem that I am not familiar with.

I would be eternally grateful if anyone could help!!

Comment: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to show the relevant code directly in your question. (And if you're going to provide a URL to an external site, at least make it clickable...)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! [Please post actual code to your specific problem and not a link to a site.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) I would also recommend reading the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) to help you get an answer as quickly as posible.

Comment: Also, there is nothing unusual about this problem. You let users scroll the container, and change the contents of the container. Why should a container scroll somewhere by itself when its content is changed? It shouldn't. Because you never asked it to. That's a misleading title that is not comme il faut at SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to apply the jQuery [.scrollLeft(0)](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) command to your page body to reset the horizontal position on each click. For example:

```
$('#products').click(function(){
    $('.slider').load("allimages.html #products2");
    $('body').scrollLeft(0);
});
```

This must be done on the page body, since your scroll bars are anchored to the whole page and not the  container.

You will need to copy this for each of your menu click events.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.scrollLeft(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) to reset the horizontal scroll position in the `<div>`.

Comment: Ah apologies for not placing the actual code in, I will definitely do that in future. I actually realised the issue lay within the html doc. I had all my div id's in one html file (for ease) but when I made separate html's they all loaded at the beginning... I will try this scrollLeft(0) however now!